# Grab the missing value after comparing 2 lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I currently have two lists

```
List<string> original = new List<string>();
List<string> edited = new List<string>();


List A            List B
------            ------
   1                 1
   2                 2
   3
```

I want to grab and display the value that is unable to be matched after comparing (which is `3` in the above example)

Comment: yes there is.. are you familiar with lambda expressions have you done anything or tried anything else beside the 2 lines of code that you have added...?

Comment: @MethodMan sorry.. i am not really familiar and into using of lambda expressions. i was thinking of using a `foreach` perhaps

Comment: Can you give an example?  It's not clear if you want to compare values at the same locations in both lists or if both lists just contain the same values regardless of order.

Comment: @juharr updated question.

Comment: @Arane My code is doing exactly this :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var notMatched = original.Except(edited).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

If you have multiple mismatched values with same value and want to be shown just once:

```
var notMatched = original.Except(edited).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: what if I've multiple mismatched values?

Comment: @Arane if you want to be shown just once use Distinct();

Answer (score 0):

> i am not really familiar and into using of lambda expressions. i was thinking of using a foreach perhaps.

Don't need a loop.

```
    List<string> deletedStuff= new List<string>();
    deletedStuff.AddRange( original.FindAll( x => ! edited.Contains( x ) ).AsEnumerable());
```